Openpyxl Formats Not Applying To Workbook
An Excel workbook has a single sheet, "DuckSheet". This sheet contains three columns. Two of these columns contain binary values of True or False:

It is intended to format the two binary value columns. A dictionary exists, with key = sheet name (of the Excel workbook) and key = a dictionary of (key = column name and value = True or False). The True or False value is the value to which the "bad_format" should be applied. If the value for column A is True, then True values in column A are to have the "bad_format" applied.
The workbook is opened, a format generated, using a bespoke function, and the format applied by column, using another bespoke function:
workbook_full_file_path = ("ducks.xlsx")
duck_checks_by_column = {"DuckSheet": {'IsPecking?': False, 'IsOutofLake': True}}
format_bad = generate_bad_format()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=workbook_full_file_path)
for ws in wb:
    rules = duck_checks_by_column[ws.title]  # Get out dictionary of formatting rules by column using the sheet name.
    apply_formats_by_column(worksheet=ws, rules_by_column=rules, format_to_apply=format_bad)

A function is used to generate a format, known as "bad_format", using openpyxl:
def generate_bad_format():
    """

    Returns: A format as a list of structure [Fill, Font]

    """

    red_fill = PatternFill(start_color='EE1111', end_color='EE1111', fill_type='solid')
    black_color_font = '000000'
    black_font = openpyxl.styles.Font(size=11, bold=True, color=black_color_font)
    bad_format = [red_fill, black_font]
    return bad_format

The formatting is applied using the apply_format_by_column function:
def apply_formats_by_column(worksheet, rules_by_column, format_to_apply):
    """

    Args:
        worksheet: An openpyxl Excel sheet object.
        rules_by_column: A dictionary of rules by column name where column name is key and value is either True or
        False. The value given indicates which binary should have the "bad" formatting applied, indicating a result
        that requires fixing.
        format_to_apply: A list of openpyxl format rules where List[0] = Fill and List[1] = Font.

    Returns: Nothing. The sheet is formatted in place.

    """

    last_row = worksheet.max_row + 1  # Assumes the same last row for all columns, which should be the case.

    for col_name, value_for_bad_format in rules_by_column.items():
        for column_cells in worksheet.iter_cols(1, worksheet.max_column): # iterate column cells by column.
            if column_cells[0].value == col_name:
                column_number_to_format = column_cells[0].column
                print(f"TESTING: A column has been found to format:\n\nName: {col_name}\nNumber: {column_number_to_format}")
                for row in range(1, last_row):
                    cell = worksheet.cell(row=row, column=column_number_to_format)
                    print(f"TESTING: Now formatting this cell: {cell} with:\nFill: {format_to_apply[0]}\nFont: {format_to_apply[1]}")
                    cell.fill = format_to_apply[0]
                    cell.font = format_to_apply[1]

Two print lines have been added that start with "TESTING". These show, by console output, that the correct cells and formats are being selected. For example, cell B4 of the "IsPecking?" column is False, and thus is for formatting. Console output:
TESTING: A column has been found to format:

Name: IsPecking?
Number: 2

...

TESTING: Now formatting this cell: <Cell 'DuckSheet'.B4> with:
Fill: <openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill object>
Parameters:
patternType='solid', fgColor=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='00EE1111', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb', bgColor=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='00EE1111', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb'
Font: <openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font object>
Parameters:
name=None, charset=None, family=None, b=True, i=False, strike=None, outline=None, shadow=None, condense=None, color=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='00000000', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb', extend=None, sz=11.0, u=None, vertAlign=None, scheme=None

The code runs, but no formatting is applied to the cells. What is the error in the code or the approach?

The workbook must be saved, via openpyxl, in order to save the results. This should be done in the "main" area after the workbook has been loaded, and the formatting applied. The full output filepath should be used. Change the "main" code to include the save line giving:
workbook_full_file_path = ("ducks.xlsx")
duck_checks_by_column = {"DuckSheet": {'IsPecking?': False, 'IsOutofLake': True}}
format_bad = generate_bad_format()
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=workbook_full_file_path)
for ws in wb:
    rules = duck_checks_by_column[ws.title]  # Get out dictionary of formatting rules by column using the sheet name.
    apply_formats_by_column(worksheet=ws, rules_by_column=rules, format_to_apply=format_bad)
wb.save(workbook_full_file_path)

